# Showing $P(\mathcal{H})$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space and $\{u_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ is an orthonormal family. Define $$P(w) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \langle w, u_i \rangle u_i.$$ I wish to show that $P(\mathcal{H})$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. I can prove that it is a subspace, but not that it is closed. How would I do so?

Comment: Look at $I - P$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{H}_1= $ the closed linear span of $\{u_i:i \in \mathbb N\}$.

Its your turn to show: $P(\mathcal{H})=\mathcal{H}_1$

Answer (score 1):

$P$ is defined by a norm-convergent expansion and recognised as self-adjoint
and idempotent, that is $P^*=P=P^2\,$. It is thus an orthogonal projector, by definition corresponding to the subspace spanned by the $u_i$.

And for a projection one generally has
$$\operatorname{Im}P = \operatorname{Ker}(I-P)\,,$$
whence the claim.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do you know that Im $P = $Ker $(I-P)$?

Comment: @HughMungus $P$ and his complement $I-P$ decompose the Hilbert space orthogonally: For each $v\in\mathcal{H}$ one has $v = P(v) + (I-P)(v)$, both summands on the RHS being orthogonal.